# How can I change background color of a FlatList row?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm learning a about lists in React-Native but I can't seem to make my code work. I want to change the background color of a certain row in a FlatList when the button inside that row is pressed. I found some answers online but most of them were complex for me to understand and didn't work(I'm very new to React-Native)

This is my code so far:

```
export default function Listt () {

    const [click, setClick] = useState(null);
    const [productsData, setproductsData] = useState([]);

    const ItemView = ({item, index}) => {
      return (
        // FlatList Item
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row} onPress={() => {setClick(index);}}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.rowtext}>
              {item[0]+ '  ' + item[1]}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    };

    async function loadInState() { 
      const keys =await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();  
      const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys); 
      setproductsData([...productsData, ...result]);
    }


    useFocusEffect(
      React.useCallback(() => {
          loadInState()        
      }, [])
    );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
        data={productsData}
        renderItem={ItemView}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />

      </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  row: {
    width:widtht,
    height:45,
    borderWidth: 2, 
    borderColor: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    textAlign:'center'
    //backgroundColor:'blue',
  },
  rowtext:{
    fontSize:17,
  },

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it with **`index`** .which uniquely identify the each item in the list
here is the code you can use.

```
const ItemView = ({item, index}) => {
      return (
        // FlatList Item
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.row,{backgroundColor: click===index ? 'tomato':'transparent'}]} onPress={() => {setClick(index);}}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.rowtext}>
              {item[0]+ '  ' + item[1]}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    };
```

Here I used my fav color tomato when you press the button but you can use as per your need and where I used transparent you can use rest of the items colors like white or whatever you want.

Comment: Ok, that works but when I click another row the background color goes back to normal. Any idea how to save the color so when I click one row it changes permanently?

Comment: then you have to declare a key i.e:backgroundColor:'default color' in each object of your array in the AsyncStorage and when you press onClick change that backgroundColor as per your desire and that will be permanent